# Proving that a finite number of poles of mermorphic $f$ exists inside a compact $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I've got some small questions regarding the following proof:

> If $f$ meromorphic on a compact $K\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ then it has finite many poles in $K$.

*Proof*

Say $f$ has infinite many poles in $K$. Consider the series $(z_n)_n$ of different poles in $K$.

Since $K$ is compact this series has a convergent subseries which converges to a $\color{red}{(1)}$ certain $z_0\in K$.

But then there does not exists a punctured disk around $z$ where $f$ would be holomorphic.

A contradiction $\color{green}{(2)}$.

#### Questions

$\color{red}{(1)}$: Does this imply $z_0$ te be a pole? *(I don't think it's of any importance for the proof itself.)*

$\color{green}{(2)}$: Is this a contradiction because then $f$ would not be holomorpic on a neighbourhood of $z_0$. Whereas meromorpic implies it to be holomorpic except on it's (**isolated**) singularities?

Comment: I'd think $z_0$ is an essential singularity if it can be classified at all.

Comment: Your proof is correct but I wrote an alternative proof, avoiding the mention of your  $z_0$, whose status I'd rather not discuss since it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

First note that a meromorphic function can only be defined on an **open** subset  of $\mathbb C$ so that we must assume that our meromorphic function $f$ is defined on an open set $U\supset K$ .

That said the subset  $S\subset U$ of singularities of $f$ is a discrete, closed (but maybe infinite) topological subspace of $U$.
But then  the subspace $S\cap K\subset K$ is discrete and closed in the compact space $K$ and is thus finite.
So indeed $K$ contains only finitely many singularities of $f$ and *a fortiori* only finitely many poles.

**Remark**
As to your  question 1), since $z_o$ does not exist it is whatever you want: a pole, the Eiffel tower or Santa Claus :-)

Comment: I haven't had any course in topology (yet) so *discrete subspaces* don't really ring a bell. Perhaps I will be able to appreciate it next year ;) How about question $\color{green}{(2)}$? Does that make sense?